# How would I automate a specific question on this website using selenium? I basically have to search up something and it’s similar to a multiple choice

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I’m new to selenium webdriver. How would I automate this part of the website? It’s like multiple choice but I don’t know what to call it, to search up more about it.

This is what I did so far, it works however I don’t know what to do for the next [bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk7In.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable\_path='/Users/name/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver')

url = '[https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G](https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G)'

driver.get(url)

//\*\[@id="guest\_last\_name"\]

//\*\[@id="guest\_email"\]

//\*\[@id="btnDailyScreeningSubmit"\]/button

driver.find\_element\_by\_xpath('')...
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Show us only the code which is causing the issue.

Comment: It’s not a issue I’m asking how to do a specific type of question

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking about how to determine which radio button you should choose, or which item in the dropdown you should choose?

Comment: I’m sorry for not clarifying, I’m asking which radio button I should choose